# API to send bitcoins from paper/cold wallet?

Tags: api, private-key, paper-wallet, coldstorage, wallet-import-format

I am making a program which will take a .wif private key, and send all funds from the wallet represented by the key to a certain address. I need this to be fully automated, but I can't seem to find any simple API which can send from a .wif. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do it yourself instead of having to send a 3rd party your private keys. [Here's one that I wrote](https://github.com/coinables/sweepkey/blob/master/app.js) using nodejs and bitcore-lib that takes a WIF and sends all funds to a different address.

https://github.com/coinables/sweepkey/blob/master/app.js

Comment: Thanks for this. While looking around i discovered `bitcoinjs-lib`, which i will just be using to generate a transaction then use some api to broadcast that (don't want to have to sync blockchain for this).